# Kafka 2.6 - KTable emit-on-change

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In Kafka 2.6 KIP-557 is implemented to change the behaviour to emit-on-change. It looks like from the PR (https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/8254) that the timestamp of the new record is compared against the existing record in the state store.

If the timestamp of the new record is different, the record is forwarded. If they are the same the bytes are compared.

If I have a stream where I do some processing, then groupByKey, and reduce. And in the reduce I compared oldValue and newValue and based on some logic return the oldValue then according to this KIP the timestamp and bytes will be the same and no event is emitted.

However if in the reduce I return the newValue it will emit the change.

We see a nightly load into our cluster of 29 million records, only some of which contain new data. We have long wished we could only emit changed records, I was just hoping someone could confirm my understanding.

KIP-557
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=145722102#content/view/144510692

Answer (score 0):

I can see the KIP you're mentioning was implemented with this story
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8770

an year after this behavior was "disabled" due to this issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-12508